# Is there a built in way of getting arrays of common sets like alphabet, numbers, etc in ios?

Tags: ios, collections, set, alphabet

I would assume there would be a convenience class somewhere where I could call say

```
NSArray *alphabet = [SomeClass lowerCaseAlphabet];
```

instead of having to write it out every time.  Is there such a class?

Comment: would it be `NSCharacterSet`?  Can't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a quick search in the docs even throws up some code using `NSMutableCharacterSet`:

addCharactersInRange:
Adds to the receiver the characters whose Unicode values are in a given range.

```
- (void)addCharactersInRange:(NSRange)aRange
```

Parameters:

aRange: 
The range of characters to add.
aRange.location is the value of the first character to add; aRange.location + aRange.length– 1 is the value of the last. If aRange.length is 0, this method has no effect.

Discussion

This code excerpt adds to a character set the lowercase English alphabetic characters:

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *aCharacterSet = [[NSMutableCharacterSet alloc] init];
NSRange lcEnglishRange;

lcEnglishRange.location = (unsigned int)'a';
lcEnglishRange.length = 26;
[aCharacterSet addCharactersInRange:lcEnglishRange];
//....
[aCharacterSet release];
```

Availability:

Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

/////////

Personal opinion: If you get stuck for a while on these things it's often just quicker to create something for yourself. In this case there's probably not much to lose by making an instance of `NSArray` with objects @"a", ..., @"z". An array of twenty-six or fifty-two characters is not very big.

Comment: True. I did end up doing that, just thought it would be convenient for future reference.  And it looks a lot spiffier in the code ;)

Comment: There isn't much to loose unless you are trying to create a multi-lingual application -- and not all languages use the same letters.

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableCharacterSet *cset = [NSMutableCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet];

I don't know if this is localizable.